# How to delete rows which were deleted in source table (Pentaho data integration)

Tags: etl, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pdi

I need to do an transformation which searches for id's coming from 2 different tables, and deletes from table 2 where the id of table two is not in table 1 (I'm using Pentaho)

That is harder than I thought, at least, o could not find the right step to use my logic.

Anyone have an idea on this?

(there are similar questions in here, but they were not useful for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **Merge join** step, defining an outer join by ID, so you retrieve all rows in *Table2* even if there's no equivalent ID in *Table1*.

You follow the Merge join by a **Filter** step, where you retrieve all the rows out of the Merge join with the ID from *Table1* NULL.

With that you have all the rows to delete.

Comment: If you just want comply with OPs question this is the correct answer. As an extention on Ana's answer, in practise deleting the removed rows is often joined by updating the changed rows. In that case better to use "merge rows (diff)" which flags rows as new, identical, changed or deleted in the main dataset, and which gives you the opportunity (together with the filter or switch step) to put specific actions on specific flags.